# Azure pipe line failed for Webpack agent

Tags: webpack, azure-devops

The Azure pipeline failed for Webpack with following error while running.

```
  [error]webpack failed
  [error]Error: Command failed: node  "D:\project\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js" --json --config 
  ../project/webpack.config.js
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
   throw err;
  Error: Cannot find module 'D:\project\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
     code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack:[]
  }
```

as i have checked it's webpack.js present in the specific location but still the pipeline shows this error.

```
PFB WebpackAgent Configuration 
 Task Version: 4.
 DisplayName : Webpack
 webpack cli arguments : --config ../project/webpack.config.js
 treat error as: errors
 treat warning as : warnings
 working folder: <folder_Name>
 webpack cli location : '/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
 stats.js location : '/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js'
```

So, please advise any solution for this issue

Comment: Do you got a webpack config file to provide

Comment: didn't get your question.

Comment: Hi @Muna Did get a chance to check out below  solution to install webpack and webpack-cli in a script task. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you were build your pipeline on local-hosted agent. Firstly, you need to check if the webpack and webpack-cli exist in the folder `D:\project\node_modules` on your local hosted agent machine.

If you specifed `working folder` field for the Webpack task. Pipeline will look for the webpack in the specified working folder. You can add a script task to install webpack and webpack-cli in the specified working folder.

For below example:
I have Webpack task configured as below screenshot. I specified `D:\test` as the `working folder`

[image]

Before Webpack task, i add a powershell task to installed `webpack` and `webpack-cli` package in folder `D:\test`

[image]

If you didnot specify the `working folder` field for the Webpack task. Pipeline will look for the webpack in the default working folder (`$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)` eg. `C:\agent\_work\1\s\node_modules`).

You still need to install `webpack` and `webpack-cli` package before webpack task.

`npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`

Above will download `webpack` and `webpack-cli` in $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\node_modules (eg.`C:\agent\_work\1\s\node_modules`)